# Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse

C:\Users\Shweta\Hi>sbt

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Shweta.sbt\0.13\plugins

[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\Shweta\Hi\project

[info] Set current project to hi (in build file:/C:/Users/Shweta/Hi/)

> run

[info] Running Hi

Hi!

[success] Total time: 1 s, completed 24 Feb, 2017 12:41:13 PM

> compile

[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 24 Feb, 2017 12:41:17 PM

> eclipse

[error] Not a valid command: eclipse (similar: help, alias)

[error] Not a valid key: eclipse (similar: deliver, licenses, clean)

[error] eclipse

[error]        ^

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `sbteclipse` plugin to your plugin definition file (for this, most likely the global one,- in your setup `C:\Users\Shweta.sbt\0.13\plugins\plugins.sbt`), after that you will be able to use `eclipse` command.

Make sure to call `reload` in sbt shell if the file was updated without leaving the shell.

Check out [sbteclipse GitHub](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `sbteclipse` plugin definition in order to execute the `eclipse` command.

You can add the plugin definition either:

- in the global plugins file at `~/.sbt/<SBT_VERSION>/plugins/plugins.sbt`
- or in your local project plugins file at `<PROJECT_DIR>/project/plugins.sbt`

The plugin has to be added by adding the definition as:

```
`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "<PLUGIN_VERSION>")`
```

For example:

```
`addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")`
```

After adding the plugin definition you can run the `eclipse` command as:

```
[play-scala-app] $ eclipse
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
...
```

See also the sbteclipse project documentation at https://github.com/sbt/sbteclipse

Answer (score 0):

With "current" undocumented as far as I know version 1.2.0 (as of Aug 6th 2018) it would be:

C:\Users\Shweta.sbt\1.0\plugins\plugins.sbt

I tested this on my Windows 10 and eclipse command was successful.